# How to create an adaptable functor in C++?

Tags: c++, functor

I have to create a functor that accepts 2 integer arguments, but use first only.
I will set second argument equal **2** using std::bind2nd. But I can't compile it.

I understand the problem is that the compiler can't make a choice between the constructor and the binary function (I'm right?). But I don't know how to fix it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

class gt_n : public std::binary_function<int, int, bool>
{
    int val;
public:
    gt_n(int v) : val(v) {}
    bool operator()(int first, int)
    {
        return first > val;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int sz = sizeof a / sizeof a[0];
    gt_n f(2);
    std::cout << std::count_if(a, a + sz,
        std::bind2nd(f(), 2)) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler messages:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:22:18: error: no match for call to '(gt_n) ()'
   std::bind2nd(f(), 2)) << std::endl;
                  ^
main.cpp:5:7: note: candidate is:
 class gt_n : public std::binary_function<int, int, bool>
       ^
main.cpp:10:7: note: bool gt_n::operator()(int, int)
  bool operator()(int first, int)
       ^
main.cpp:10:7: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
```

Comment: `std::bind2nd` is marked deprecated. You ought not use it in new code.

Comment: avoid using `std::bind2nd` prefer to use `std::bind` or a lambda function.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

You already created your functor in the line `gt_n f(2);` (via the constructor). If you pass `f()` to `std::bind2nd`, you try to call `operator()()` which does not exist. Just pass the functor (`f`): `std::bind2nd(f, 2))`.

Two additional notes:

- As pointed out in the comments, `std::bind2nd` is deprecated. You should use `std::bind`. With C++11, `std::binary_function` and `std::unary_function` are deprecated too. You no longer have to extend them.
- `std::count_if` does not require a binary but a unary predicate. `operator()` should only have one argument.